# How to create an infinite receiver/listener in Azure Service Bus - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azureservicebus, messaging

Requirement is to create a background listener process that will receive and process the message from the service bus subscriptions.
I have searched many resources but couldnt able to find a solution. The message should not be in DELETE mode but rather be in PEEK_LOCK mode so that we can abandon the messages whenever an error occurs in the processing logic where it will re queue again.
Service bus tier : Standard.
Thank you.

Comment: You've read many resources but missed official examples like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus?

Comment: Is the error connecting to the service bus or to process the message?

Comment: @Tom I have read jms. no support of azure service bus sessions. 
    Referred this. https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/444

Comment: @J_D error is in the process message